# Debian: Can't bring eth0 down or up with ifdown or ifup

Tags: debian, ifconfig, eth0

I can't bring eth0 down or up with ifdown or ifup

```
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
```

but ifconfig shows me

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:3e:4d:09:5f
          inet addr:192.168.0.3  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

It's a xen guest i just setup, in another guest it does work, how can i overcome this?

Comment: 1) What Linux Distribution are you using? 2) How are you running the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just solved this, i had a gateway set which wasn't in range of the subnet but i thought i could reload the config with ifdown and ifup. after setting the correct gateway and rebooting it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Compare the files /etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0 on both systems. Maybe something is missing there.

Comment: /etc/sysconfig is for Redhat/Centos